# How can I use alias in Sqlmodel library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, sqlmodel

I am learning to use new Sqlmodel library in Python. As far as i understand, it is based on two libraries: Sqlalchemy and Pydantic.

## Question:

Is there any option in Sqlmodel to use **alias** parameter in Field? In my custom class i have some attributes, which have exactly same names as attributes of parent classes (for example "schema" attribute of SQLModel base class)

I've tried to use alias as in Pydantic, but failed.

**Succesful usage with Pydantic library:**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List, Optional

class Editable(BaseModel):
    only_fact: Optional[bool] = Field(default=None)
    dispose: Optional[int] = Field(default=None)
    optional: Optional[bool] = Field(default=None)

class SchemaDetail(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    parent_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None)
    values: List[float]

class MyClass(BaseModel):
   editable_: Editable = Field(alias='editable')
   schema_: List[SchemaDetail] = Field(alias='schema')
```

**Errors when using Sqlmodel library:**

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

from typing import List, Optional

class Editable(SQLModel):
    only_fact: Optional[bool] = Field(default=None)
    dispose: Optional[int] = Field(default=None)
    optional: Optional[bool] = Field(default=None)

class SchemaDetail(SQLModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    parent_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None)
    values: List[float]

class MyClass(SQLModel):
   editable_: Editable = Field(alias='editable')
   schema_: List[SchemaDetail] = Field(alias='schema')
```

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: what version of sqlModel do you use?

Comment: @LoukasPap I'm using sqlmodel==0.0.14

Comment: @AdesojiAlu 
I'm trying to unpack result schema in function:

def get_my_class() -> Any:
    result = example_schema

    return MyClass(**result)

I'm getting these errors:

```pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for MyClass
editable_
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'editable': {'only_fact'..., 'values': [4, 5, 6]}]}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
schema_
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'editable': {'only_fact'..., 'values': [4, 5, 6]}]}, input_type=dict]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the official repository's discussion: https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/discussions/725. As the title says:

> Field alias broken since SQLModel 0.0.14

Comment: Rolled back to 0.0.13 version of Sqlmodel, it seemed to fix this issue. Thanks for answering!

Comment: There is a PR related to this issue: https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/pull/774. You could use a fork in the meantime. I would not recommend downgrading since SQLModel 0.0.14 introduces Pydantic v2 which has a lot of breaking changes.